# Insecure <form> call on Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ssl, https

I am going crazy trying to get my site secure. There is a form that is supposedly not allowing my site SSL

When I look it up on WhyNoPadLock.com I get:

> Insecure  call    Found on line # 247 in file:
>   rideyellow.com/index.html

I looked through the style sheet and have changed all of the hard coded domain links to https already.

We do have a Call Now button in the header that was custom coded into the site. this works with Javascript. Its a plugin called Anything Pop Up. Could this Javascript be the root of the problem? How can I fix this issue?

I cannot find this "form" anywhere. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's on line #247?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I visited your site. You are loading mixed content, as can be seen through the following Chrome console warning:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://rideyellow.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure video
>   'http://rideyellow.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/RideYellow_1.mp4'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Also, you do have a form element in line 247, but you seem to be calling its action over HTTPS, so it should be fine. If you still get issues over this, leave out the action attribute altogether, as you're just referencing the same page.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, the video was no problem, but I did take out that line of code completely and it resolved the issue!

Comment: Glad to help. However, your site is still not showing up as secure on Chrome, because of the aforementioned video.