# Insecure <form> call. Found on index.html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, ssl

I recently moved one of my site to HTTPS with SSL certificate, I tested it on whynopadlock.com and it shows me Insecure `<form>` call. Found on line # 65 in file: on index page of my website. I did found this a thread on the same issue but it doesn't have a solution. ( [Insecure <form> call on Wordpress Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105503/insecure-form-call-on-wordpress-site) ). I did found a link with HTTP: that may be causing the issue. Rest all the links are HTTPS.

```
<div class="wp-google-badge wp-google-badge-fixed" onclick="document.querySelector('.wp-gr .wp-google-form').style.display='block'" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

This ain't a form but a Google review plugin which I am using on the website. I tried disabling the plugin but no success. Why on earth I am getting this issue when my site is all secured.

Comment: probably this bit `temtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"`  because its not `https` that would be my guess, all URLs should be HTTPs when using HTTPs this includes any images such as a site logo, basically everything.  Mixed content.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're using http in your code, and analytic system is kinda bad, thinking that you're insecure. Just edit your code, change http to https, in itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing a url instead of http or https you should do something like the below code.

```
<div class="wp-google-badge wp-google-badge-fixed" onclick="document.querySelector('.wp-gr .wp-google-form').style.display='block'" itemscope itemtype="//schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

Please take note of // everytime.